# Solving quadratic complex equation

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to solve this equation:

> $z^2+2iz+11-16i=0$
>
> where $z=x+iy$ with $ x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

I tried it with the quadratic formula $z_{1/2}=- \frac p2 \pm \sqrt{\left(\frac p2\right)^2 -q}$ and get:

$z_{1/2}=-i \pm \sqrt{i^2-11+16i} \\ \Leftrightarrow z_{1/2}=-i \pm \sqrt{12i^2+16i} $

Now I'm stucking. Any ideas how it's going on?

Comment: Use $i^2=-1$ to simplify and then reduce the expression $\sqrt{a+bi}$ to the form $c+di$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing the square might be simpler:

$z^2+2iz+i^2 = -11+16i+i^2$

$(z+i)^2 = -12+16i$

$z = -i \pm \sqrt{-12+16i}$

$z = -i \pm 2\sqrt{-3+4i}$ (factor out a $4$ from under the squareroot).

To simplify $\sqrt{-3+4i} = a+bi$, we need to find reals $a,b$ such that $(a+bi)^2 = (a^2-b^2)+(2ab)i = -3+4i$.

Since the numbers are small, you can try guessing integers for $a,b$.

Since $a = 1$ and $b = 2$ work, $1+2i$ is a value for $\sqrt{-3+4i}$. Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

$(2 + 4i)^2 = 2^2 + 2\cdot2\cdot4i + 4^2 i^2 = 4 +16i - 16 = (-12) + 16i$. Then the result is $-i \pm (2+4i)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\sqrt{12i^2+16i}=2\sqrt{-3+4i}=\sqrt{(1+2i)^2}=\pm(1+2i).
$$

Comment: Thanks for the note. But Jimmy's answer showed me how to know that $(-3+4i)=(1+2i)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way, you have $z_1 + z_2 = -2i$ and $z_1 z_2 = 11-16i$.  The first equation gives you $z_1 = a+bi \implies z_2 = -a-(2+b)i$.

So from the second equation we are left to solve in reals
$$-a^2+2b+b^2=11,\; a+ab=8 \implies (a, b) = (-2, -5)$$